# UILabel.attributedText set attributes once and then just change text (string)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

How to set UILabel text attributes only once and then just change text (string)

```
mTextValue.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "STRING", 
       attributes: 
           [NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth: -3.0,      
            NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor: UIColor.black])


mTextValue.text = "NEW STRING" // won't change anything
```

or to set new string do I have to set `NSAttributedString` to `.attributedText` again and again?

Comment: if you want attributedText then you need to create attributed string and set attributedText.

Comment: @Neel Bhasin it's easier to read code when there is no scrolls

Comment: but that was scrolling already with extra spaces

Comment: @NeelBhasin yes I do it already, but text is going to be changed every 1 sec, why there is no option just to change text after I already set attributes why do I have to set attributes again if I already did

Comment: If you are looking for iOS API there might be none, you may need to write a wrapper class/method of your own some where.

Comment: Because playing with `text` and `attributedText` properties of `UILabel` are quite "exclusive". You can't do that. You need to use one of them, but using both of them will have unexpected results. And `NSAttributedString` is much more "complex" than NSString, so it's not that simple.

Comment: @Larme I understand I just wrote `text` method here to show that I want to change text without setting attributes again, I don't have it really in my code, just to explain what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could declare a mutableAttributed string separat and change the string of it like here:

```
let yourString = "my string"
let yourAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth: -3.0, NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor: UIColor.black] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: yourString, attributes: yourAttributes)

let yourNewString = "my new string"
mutableAttributedString.mutableString.setString(yourNewString)
```

Full example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        mutableAttributedString.mutableString.setString("new string")
        mainLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let yourString = "my string"
        let yourAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth: -3.0, NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor: UIColor.blue] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
        mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: yourString, attributes: yourAttributes)

        mainLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
    }

}
```

Comment: doesn't work (swift 4): `let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "09:52:35", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth: -3.0,                           NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor: UIColor.black] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])
        
        mTextValue.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
        
        mutableAttributedString.mutableString.setString("09:52:36")`

Comment: text won't change after I set `mTextValue.attributedText = mutableAttributedString ` and trying to set new string after it `mutableAttributedString.mutableString.setString("new string")`

Comment: What is myTextValue? A label, a button ?

Comment: it is a `UILabel`

Comment: Ok i'll check it out now

Comment: Check out the full example. You should store the mutableAttributedString as member variable of the viewController to change its string value

Comment: instead of button event I tried dispatch main asynAfter (1 sec) and it worked